# remove validation zend form element javascript/jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, zend-framework

I want to disable the validation on one of the zend form element based on the input on another element on the same form. I need to achieve this using javascript/jquery. Something very common but very surprisingly couldn't find it over the internet.

e.g.

In the controller:

```
$oFormMassEdit = new Account_Form_Returns_Return();
$this->view->form = $oFormMassEdit;
```

In Account_Form_Returns_Return's constructor:

```
$oNoteElement = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('option', array(
                                                'required'  => true,
                                  ));
$this->addElemet($oNoteElement)

$oReasonElement = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('note', array(
            'multiOptions'  => array (
                'return'  => 'return',
                'defect'  => 'Kaput',
                'other'   => 'Anderer Grund'
            ),
            'required'      => true,
                    ));
$this->addElement($oReasonElement);

$this->addDisplayGroup(array('note', 'option'), 'main', array('legend' => 'Retouren'));

$this->addElement('button','send', array(
           'type'   => 'submit',
           'label'  => 'Methode speichern',
        ));
```

and finally in the view,

```
<?= $this->form; ?>
```

Comment: Can you show us some code..

Comment: So, I have edited my question to show you how to create a zend form and then render it on the view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript can't (not in a sensible way) switch Zend_Form configuration. What you can do is changing the 'required' param for certain form fields on validation. For example; If you want to allow fieldTwo to be empty if fieldOne has 'desiredValue' as value you can achieve this using the following function in your form:

```
public function isValid($data) {
    if('desiredValue' == $data['fieldOne'])) {
        $this->getElement('fieldTwo')->setRequired(false);
    }

    return parent::isValid($data);
}
```

Comment: ok, the problem is that I get some post data from page A and then based on this post data, I construct page B. On page B, I display a form, this form is based on post data got from page A. Now page C validates the form created on page B and if it is invalidated, user should get back to page B with highlighted invalid fields.

Comment: To keep it simple use action B as renderer of form and validation of it. You can post values of the POST of page A to the form of page B and use them in the form to add/remove fields, change validators etc.

Comment: Rather than *remove* the validator in question, you could *conditionally add* it in `$form->isValid()` before calling `parent::isValid()`. See [this post](http://www.jeremykendall.net/2009/01/19/dynamically-adding-elements-to-zend-form/) from Jeremy Kendall for one approach to dynamically changing the form behavior (adding fields, in his case) based on actions that take place on the client-side. He uses a `preValidate()` method, but you could probably just override `isValid()` as described above, which keeps the controller-flow pretty standard.

Comment: I agree with this possibility. Whatever suits your situation at best.